# Adding spacing and blank lines to Open Office XML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to output a word file using Open Office XML, but can't seem to get spacing correct.

```
Variable name:ATTEND
 Description:Student's attendance status during the
```

I want the word file to be this (with spaces after the :):

```
Variable name: ATTEND
Description:Student's attendance status during the
```

My code is as follow, and the spacing disappears:

```
start of my function
// Add a new main document part. 
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

            // Create the Document DOM.
            mainPart.Document = new Document();

            Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());

            ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties
            (
                new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "No Spacing" },
                new SpacingBetweenLines() { After = "0" }
            );

            Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(paragraphProperties));
            Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());

            RunProperties runProperties = run.AppendChild(new RunProperties(new Bold()));
            run.AppendChild(new Text("Variable name: "));

            run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
            run.AppendChild(new Text(" ATTEND"));

            para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());

            run = para.AppendChild(new Run());

            runProperties = run.AppendChild(new RunProperties(new Bold()));
            run.AppendChild(new Text("Description: "));

            run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
            run.AppendChild(new Text(" Student's attendance status during the "));


            // Save changes to the main document part. 
            wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Usually, OpenXML will trim every `Text` member. To preserve the spaces in each `Text` member, so you will have this `test test` instead of `test test`, set the special `Space` property of the `Text` member:

`Text txt = new Text("text here      ") { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };`